# Мне нужно создать объект пользователь из класса пользователи передавая туда значения из списка словарей

Tags: python, json, ооп, list, словари

Мне нужно создать объект пользователь из класса пользователи передавая туда значения из списка словарей

у меня есть класс пользователи который имеет параметры:

```
class User:
def __init__(self, user_id, name, time_created, gender, last_name, premium, city, age, ip, birth_day, balance):
    self.user_id = user_id
    self.name = name
    self.time_created = time_created
    self.gender = gender
    self.last_name = last_name
    self.premium = premium
    self.city = city
    self.age = age
    self.ip = ip
    self.birth_day = birth_day
    self.balance = balance
```

мне нужно создать объекты пользователей из списка вот пример списка:

```
{"name": "Olive", "time_created": 1664662362, "gender": "female", "last_name": "Tilghman", "city": "NY", "age": 38, "premium": null, "ip": "192.168.0.110", "birth_day": "01.01", "balance": 55.99832723139716, "user_id": 1321}{"name": "Sherry", "time_created": 1664662362, "gender": "female", "last_name": "Kong", "age": 48, "city": "NY", "premium": null, "ip": "192.168.0.110", "birth_day": "01.01", "balance": 55.99832723139716, "user_id": 1322}{"name": "Viola", "time_created": 1664662362, "gender": "female", "age": 57, "last_name": "Smith", "city": "NY", "premium": null, "ip": "192.168.0.110", "birth_day": "01.01", "balance": 55.99832723139716, "user_id": 1323}{"name": "Dewey", "time_created": 1664662362, "gender": "female", "last_name": "Smith", "city": "NY", "age": 38, "premium": null, "ip": "192.168.0.110", "birth_day": "01.01", "balance": 55.99832723139716, "user_id": 1324}{"name": "Ida", "time_created": 1664662362, "gender": "female", "last_name": "Martin", "city": "NY", "age": 38, "premium": null, "ip": "192.168.0.110", "birth_day": "01.01", "balance": 55.99832723139716, "user_id": 1325}{"name": "Lester", "time_created": 1664662362, "gender": "male", "city": "NY", "premium": false, "last_name": "Smith", "age": 38, "ip": "192.168.0.110", "birth_day": "01.01", "balance": 55.99832723139716, "user_id": 1326}{"name": "Todd", "time_created": 1664662362, "gender": "male", "age": 38, "last_name": "Smith", "city": "NY", "premium": null, "ip": "192.168.0.110", "birth_day": "01.01", "balance": 55.99832723139716, "user_id": 1327}
```

то есть нужно значение из списка словарей передать в класс и создать объекты пользователей для роботы с ним потом, как это реализовать?

Comment: вопрос то в чем?

Comment: как это реализовать?

Comment: `for d in dictList: o = User(**d)`

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: а как потом можно вызвать созданных пользователей для роботы с ними, например чтоб вывести первого пользователя?

Comment: или просто в loop`e действия записывать над обьектами созданами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать распаковку словаря:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, user_id, name, time_created, gender, last_name, premium, city, age, ip, birth_day, balance):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.name = name
        self.time_created = time_created
        self.gender = gender
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.premium = premium
        self.city = city
        self.age = age
        self.ip = ip
        self.birth_day = birth_day
        self.balance = balance

null = None
false = False

data = [
    {"name": "Olive", "time_created": 1664662362, "gender": "female", "last_name": "Tilghman", "city": "NY", "age": 38, "premium": null, "ip": "192.168.0.110", "birth_day": "01.01", "balance": 55.99832723139716, "user_id": 1321},
    {"name": "Sherry", "time_created": 1664662362, "gender": "female", "last_name": "Kong", "age": 48, "city": "NY", "premium": null, "ip": "192.168.0.110", "birth_day": "01.01", "balance": 55.99832723139716, "user_id": 1322},
    {"name": "Viola", "time_created": 1664662362, "gender": "female", "age": 57, "last_name": "Smith", "city": "NY", "premium": null, "ip": "192.168.0.110", "birth_day": "01.01", "balance": 55.99832723139716, "user_id": 1323},
    {"name": "Dewey", "time_created": 1664662362, "gender": "female", "last_name": "Smith", "city": "NY", "age": 38, "premium": null, "ip": "192.168.0.110", "birth_day": "01.01", "balance": 55.99832723139716, "user_id": 1324},
    {"name": "Ida", "time_created": 1664662362, "gender": "female", "last_name": "Martin", "city": "NY", "age": 38, "premium": null, "ip": "192.168.0.110", "birth_day": "01.01", "balance": 55.99832723139716, "user_id": 1325},
    {"name": "Lester", "time_created": 1664662362, "gender": "male", "city": "NY", "premium": false, "last_name": "Smith", "age": 38, "ip": "192.168.0.110", "birth_day": "01.01", "balance": 55.99832723139716, "user_id": 1326},
    {"name": "Todd", "time_created": 1664662362, "gender": "male", "age": 38, "last_name": "Smith", "city": "NY", "premium": null, "ip": "192.168.0.110", "birth_day": "01.01", "balance": 55.99832723139716, "user_id": 1327}
]

users = [User(**item) for item in data]
```

Проверить, что получилось, можно так:

```
for user in users:
    print(user.__dict__)
```

Но лучше бы конечно реализовать для класса `User` метод `__str__` и сделать в нём вывод нужных вам полей в понятной вам форме и тогда можно будет печатать объект в понятном виде просто через `print(user)`.

Comment: Большое спасибо, не подскажите еще как вывести юзеров списком чтоб проверить все ли передалось? Потому что простой принт выводит обьектом

Comment: @GeorgeRybojchuk Добавил код и пояснение